# Conversion of coordinates of "Bochum coordinate system"

Tags: qgis, data, convert, coordinates

I need to convert historic coordinate data into more recent Gauß-Krueger data. Specifically, I need to convert "Bochum coordinates" used till 1960 in the local coal mines into DHDN/Gauß-Krüger zone 2 (EPSG 31466, ID 2646).
Is there in QGis a tool (similar to that that seems to exist is ESRI ArcGIS) that I can use for this job?

Answer (score 1):

I found a WMS with a map in your Coordinate System at `http://212.23.139.170:8080/internet/synserver?project=hist_karten`

---

**EDIT**

The projection is also called "Preußisches Katastersystem Bochum" and was a [Soldner projection](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soldner-Koordinatensystem) used before Gauss-Krüger. Center of Origin in Bochum City was 51° 29' 1,2540" North 24° 53' 16,0590" East of **Ferro** Meridian.

The proj string for that is:

```
+proj=cass +lat_0=51.48373533 +lon_0=7.22115822 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=598.1,73.7,418.2,0.202,0.045,-2.455,6.7 +units=m +no_defs
```

This can be added to QGIS as custom CRS, or use it with GDAL cs2cs.

If the coordinates are all positive, you have to take the coordinate for Bochum City as x_0 and y_0.

You can find old transformation formulas in

[Zeitschrift für Vermessungswesen 1898](http://archive.org/stream/zeitschriftfrve22vermgoog#page/n20/mode/2up)

at page 6.

---

**Edit 2**

You can find proj parameters for all prussian cataster systems [in this patch for spatialite](https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/ci/332f5e8690ca7e0662e26c425d5515001429451b?sbs=0)

The coordinates for all German systems of that time can be found in this [Book](http://openlibrary.org/books/OL20478897M/Anleitung_zur_Berechnung_geod%C3%A4tischer_Coordinaten...)