# Which EPSG setting when georeferencing German maps from 1880s?

Tags: coordinate-system, georeferencing, epsg, germany

I'm trying to georeference a map from 1881 that was created by the Preußische Landesaufnahme. When using Gauß-Krüger (EPSG:31467), my map section always ends up way too far in the east. I've found out by now that they used another meridian back in the days, the Ferro Meridian.

Is there a preset EPSG in QGIS for the Preußische Landesaufnahme to compensate the differences to todays coordinate systems?

Comment: EPSG does have Ferro-based ProjCRS but not for Germany--only for Austria, Czech Republic, and Slovakia.

Comment: Maybe related: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/68805/conversion-of-coordinates-of-bochum-coordinate-system. If you can supply a link to the map, or upload it in a readable resolution, I could investigate further.

Answer (score 1):

set up a userdefined CRS and use the following proj4 parameters:

+proj=longlat +ellps=bessel +datum=potsdam +pm=-17.66666666666667 +no_defs.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  A good answer should include explanation as to *how* to use your answer, *what* it does and *why*.  Please **[edit]** your answer to include more information.  Short answers with little information may be downvoted or removed.